# Spring integration: http inbound gateway detect empty body and use 204 code

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I have the following HTTP inbound gateway:

```
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow httpInbound() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Http.inboundGateway("/").requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST)))
        .channel(SOME_CHANNEL_NAME).get();
  }
```

And this service for the reply:

```
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = SOME_CHANNEL_NAME)
  public String receive() {
    //process string
    return string;
  }
```

But this is returning 200 even when the reply is empty (""). I would like a 204 status code when string is empty and 200 when string is not empty. Of course I can do this:

```
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = SOME_CHANNEL_NAME)
  public GenericMessage receive() {
    //process string
    return "".equals(string) ? new GenericMessage<>("", Map.of(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, 204)) : new GenericMessage<>(string, Map.of(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, 200));
  }
```

But I'm asking this because maybe there is an easier and cleaner way (maybe configuring the inbound gateway or using an http outbound gateway).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is fully OK. Another way is return just a `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT` as a payload. You also can return a whole `ResponseEntity`. You also can return `null` and set a `replyTimeout()` to some limited number. Then you can set a `statusCodeFunction()` to produce that `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT`.